# Merging dataframes but not returning any matches even when I know there are matches

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have data from two sources that I am trying to merge. They each have one column that contains common key identifiers. df1 is a list of calls with a key identifier for each record, and df2 is a list of key identifiers with a sum of calls for each.

df1 has Key Identifiers that are not on df2, and there are Key Identifiers that will repeat many times on df1 from df2. I want the call number that relates to the Key Identifier to be merged over from df2 to df1 on all records.

My data looks like this (There are 5,529,281 records in df1 and 25,203 records in df2. This is just a very small made up sample of what it looks like. The Key Identifiers can be over 50 characters and they're not all the same length.):

```
df1

RowDate    StartTime           Customer#       Key Identifier1   CallDuration   Transfer   Agent   CallID                      
2021-03-09  2021-03-09 16:23:28  123456789098765 12354a9b6542cde4465gh154687gg854sr954 1.28  N balk 0987654321 
2021-04-05  2021-04-05 10:16:43  123456789098765 96582gf557fs226561ag55843saa245624fee 11.55 Y alcok 1234567890 


df2

Key Identifier2                       Calls 
12354a9b6542cde4465gh154687gg854sr954  1 
256gd46871shr4684ere156871354shr484rg  2 
96582gf557fs226561ag55843saa245624fee  1
```

Here is what I tried, and it merges the dfs but everything from df2 is NaN, but I have confirmed that there are matches in the two Key Identifier columns.

```
df_group = df1.merge(df2, left_on=['Key Identifier1'], right_on=['Key Identifier2'], how='left')
```

Comment: There is a typo in your code, `right_on=['Key Identifer2']` -> `right_on=['Key Identifier2']`. Anyway, when I run the code, `Call Number` column from df2 is well merged and I cant see the values.

Comment: @SangkeunPark thanks for calling out the typo - in my original code that's not the issue thankfully, just when I was retyping it over here.

Comment: Oh, there is a typo on my comment. when I run the code, Call Number column from df2 is well merged and I can see the correct values, at least with your sample data. If you update more sample data, I can test it again.

Comment: you should put data as DataFrame or list in code - so we could copy it and use in code.

Comment: @furas I updated it, hopefully that helps. It's a tiny made up sample of a huge huge dataset - just not sure why it's not matching any of the key identifiers when I know for sure there are matches. I can't have the actual data here due to sensitivity reasons.